# Regex to extract string between two symbols

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a string like this

> Affiliation / Facility Name = Provider 1069860 # Admissions = 1 #
>   Potentially Avoidable = 0

I want a Regex Expression to extract the value Provider 1069860 from it.

I tried "= [a-zA-Z]+ #" but it is giving a blank result

Comment: You might provide the code you wrote so far and explain the requirements. See, your `[A-Za-z]+` only matches letters while there are digits, too. You might try `= [\w ]+ #` to fix this. `regExp.Global` property must be set to *False*.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

With this : 
`.*Facility Name = ([a-zA-Z 0-9]+) #.*`

You match what you want in the match group one

https://regex101.com/r/EnYZ55/1